# Should __ne__ be implemented as the negation of __eq__?

Tags: python, comparison, operators, inequality, python-datamodel

I have a class where I want to override the `__eq__` method. It seems to make sense that I should override the `__ne__` method as well. Should I implement `__ne__` as the negation of `__eq__` as such or is it a bad idea?

```py
class A:

    def __init__(self, state):
        self.state = state

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.state == other.state

    def __ne__(self, other):
        return not self.__eq__(other)
```

Answer (score 66, accepted):

Yes, that's perfectly fine.  In fact, [the documentation](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__ne__) urges you to define `__ne__` when you define `__eq__`:

> There are no implied relationships
>   among the comparison operators. The
>   truth of `x==y` does not imply that `x!=y`
>   is false. Accordingly, when defining
>   `__eq__()`, one should also define `__ne__()` so that the operators will behave as expected.

In a lot of cases (such as this one), it will be as simple as negating the result of `__eq__`, but not always.

Comment: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30676267/916568) is the right answer (down here, by @aaron-hall). The documentation you quoted does *not* encourage you to implement `__ne__` using `__eq__`, only that you implement it.

Comment: @guyarad: Actually, Aaron's answer is still slightly wrong thanks to not properly delegating; instead of treating a `NotImplemented` return from one side as a cue to delegate to `__ne__` on the other side, `not self == other` is (assuming the operand's `__eq__` doesn't know how to compare the other operand) implicitly delegating to `__eq__` from the other side, then inverting it. For weird types, e.g. the SQLAlchemy ORM's fields, this [causes problems](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35781654/364696).

Comment: ShadowRanger's criticism would only apply to very pathological cases (IMHO) and  is fully addressed in my answer below.

Comment: The newer documentations (for 3.7 at least, might be even earlier) `__ne__` delegates automatically to `__eq__` and the quote in this answer no longer exists in the docs. Bottom line it is perfectly pythonic to only implement `__eq__` and let `__ne__` delegate.

Answer (score 183):

> Python, should I implement `__ne__()` operator based on `__eq__`?

### Short Answer: Don't implement it, but if you must, use `==`, not `__eq__`

In Python 3, `!=` is the negation of `==` by default, so you are not even required to write a `__ne__`, and the documentation is no longer opinionated on writing one.

Generally speaking, for Python 3-only code, don't write one unless you need to overshadow the parent implementation, e.g. for a builtin object.

That is, keep in mind [Raymond Hettinger's comment](https://bugs.python.org/issue4395):

> The `__ne__` method follows automatically from `__eq__` only if
>   `__ne__` isn't already defined in a superclass.  So, if you're
>   inheriting from a builtin, it's best to override both.

If you need your code to work in Python 2, follow the recommendation for Python 2 and it will work in Python 3 just fine.

In Python 2, Python itself does not automatically implement any operation in terms of another - therefore, you should define the `__ne__` in terms of `==` instead of the `__eq__`.
E.G.

```py
class A(object):
    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.value == other.value

    def __ne__(self, other):
        return not self == other # NOT `return not self.__eq__(other)`
```

See proof that

- implementing `__ne__()` operator based on `__eq__` and
- not implementing `__ne__` in Python 2 at all

provides incorrect behavior in the demonstration below.

### Long Answer

The [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__ne__) for Python 2 says:

> There are no implied relationships among the comparison operators. The
>   truth of `x==y` does not imply that `x!=y` is false. Accordingly, when
>   defining `__eq__()`, one should also define `__ne__()` so that the
>   operators will behave as expected.

So that means that if we define `__ne__` in terms of the inverse of `__eq__`, we can get consistent behavior.

This section of the documentation has been updated for [Python 3:](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__ne__)

> By default, `__ne__()` delegates to `__eq__()` and inverts the result
>   unless it is `NotImplemented`.

and in the ["what's new" section](https://docs.python.org/3.0/whatsnew/3.0.html#operators-and-special-methods), we see this behavior has changed:

> - `!=` now returns the opposite of `==`, unless `==` returns `NotImplemented`.

*For implementing `__ne__`, we prefer to use the `==` operator* instead of using the `__eq__` method directly so that if `self.__eq__(other)` of a subclass returns `NotImplemented` for the type checked, Python will appropriately check `other.__eq__(self)` [From the documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#the-standard-type-hierarchy):

> #### The `NotImplemented` object
>
> This type has a single value. There is a single object with this value. This object is accessed through the built-in name
>   `NotImplemented`. Numeric methods and rich comparison methods may return
>   this value if they do not implement the operation for the operands
>   provided. (The interpreter will then try the reflected operation, or
>   some other fallback, depending on the operator.) Its truth value is
>   true.

When given a rich comparison operator, if they're not the same type, Python checks if the `other` is a subtype, and if it has that operator defined, it uses the `other`'s method first (inverse for `<`, `<=`, `>=` and `>`). If `NotImplemented` is returned, *then* it uses the opposite's method. (It does *not* check for the same method twice.) Using the `==` operator allows for this logic to take place.

---

### Expectations

Semantically, you should implement `__ne__` in terms of the check for equality because users of your class will expect the following functions to be equivalent for all instances of A.:

```py
def negation_of_equals(inst1, inst2):
    """always should return same as not_equals(inst1, inst2)"""
    return not inst1 == inst2

def not_equals(inst1, inst2):
    """always should return same as negation_of_equals(inst1, inst2)"""
    return inst1 != inst2
```

That is, both of the above functions should *always* return the same result. But this is dependent on the programmer.

### Demonstration of unexpected behavior when defining `__ne__` based on `__eq__`:

First the setup:

```py
class BaseEquatable(object):
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x
    def __eq__(self, other):
        return isinstance(other, BaseEquatable) and self.x == other.x

class ComparableWrong(BaseEquatable):
    def __ne__(self, other):
        return not self.__eq__(other)

class ComparableRight(BaseEquatable):
    def __ne__(self, other):
        return not self == other

class EqMixin(object):
    def __eq__(self, other):
        """override Base __eq__ & bounce to other for __eq__, e.g. 
        if issubclass(type(self), type(other)): # True in this example
        """
        return NotImplemented

class ChildComparableWrong(EqMixin, ComparableWrong):
    """__ne__ the wrong way (__eq__ directly)"""

class ChildComparableRight(EqMixin, ComparableRight):
    """__ne__ the right way (uses ==)"""

class ChildComparablePy3(EqMixin, BaseEquatable):
    """No __ne__, only right in Python 3."""
```

Instantiate non-equivalent instances:

```py
right1, right2 = ComparableRight(1), ChildComparableRight(2)
wrong1, wrong2 = ComparableWrong(1), ChildComparableWrong(2)
right_py3_1, right_py3_2 = BaseEquatable(1), ChildComparablePy3(2)
```

#### Expected Behavior:

(Note: while every second assertion of each of the below is equivalent and therefore logically redundant to the one before it, I'm including them to demonstrate that *order does not matter when one is a subclass of the other.*)

These instances have `__ne__` implemented with `==`:

```
assert not right1 == right2
assert not right2 == right1
assert right1 != right2
assert right2 != right1
```

These instances, testing under Python 3, also work correctly:

```
assert not right_py3_1 == right_py3_2
assert not right_py3_2 == right_py3_1
assert right_py3_1 != right_py3_2
assert right_py3_2 != right_py3_1
```

And recall that these have `__ne__` implemented with `__eq__` - while this is the expected behavior, the implementation is incorrect:

```
assert not wrong1 == wrong2         # These are contradicted by the
assert not wrong2 == wrong1         # below unexpected behavior!
```

#### Unexpected Behavior:

Note that this comparison contradicts the comparisons above (`not wrong1 == wrong2`).

```
>>> assert wrong1 != wrong2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AssertionError
```

and,

```
>>> assert wrong2 != wrong1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AssertionError
```

#### Don't skip `__ne__` in Python 2

For evidence that you should not skip implementing `__ne__` in Python 2, see these equivalent objects:

```
>>> right_py3_1, right_py3_1child = BaseEquatable(1), ChildComparablePy3(1)
>>> right_py3_1 != right_py3_1child # as evaluated in Python 2!
True
```

The above result should be `False`!

### Python 3 source

The default CPython implementation for `__ne__` is in [`typeobject.c` in `object_richcompare`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/typeobject.c#L3765):

```c
case Py_NE:
    /* By default, __ne__() delegates to __eq__() and inverts the result,
       unless the latter returns NotImplemented. */
    if (Py_TYPE(self)->tp_richcompare == NULL) {
        res = Py_NotImplemented;
        Py_INCREF(res);
        break;
    }
    res = (*Py_TYPE(self)->tp_richcompare)(self, other, Py_EQ);
    if (res != NULL && res != Py_NotImplemented) {
        int ok = PyObject_IsTrue(res);
        Py_DECREF(res);
        if (ok < 0)
            res = NULL;
        else {
            if (ok)
                res = Py_False;
            else
                res = Py_True;
            Py_INCREF(res);
        }
    }
    break;
```

### But the default `__ne__` uses `__eq__`?

Python 3's default `__ne__` implementation detail at the C level uses `__eq__` because the higher level `==` ([PyObject_RichCompare](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/object.html#c.PyObject_RichCompare)) would be less efficient - and therefore it must also handle `NotImplemented`.

If `__eq__` is correctly implemented, then the negation of `==` is also correct - and it allows us to avoid low level implementation details in our `__ne__`.

Using `==` allows us to keep our low level logic in *one* place, and *avoid* addressing `NotImplemented` in `__ne__`.

One might incorrectly assume that `==` may return `NotImplemented`.

It actually uses the same logic as the default implementation of `__eq__`, which checks for identity (see [do_richcompare](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/object.c#L642) and our evidence below)

```
class Foo:
    def __ne__(self, other):
        return NotImplemented
    __eq__ = __ne__

f = Foo()
f2 = Foo()
```

And the comparisons:

```
>>> f == f
True
>>> f != f
False
>>> f2 == f
False
>>> f2 != f
True
```

### Performance

Don't take my word for it, let's see what's more performant:

```
class CLevel:
    "Use default logic programmed in C"

class HighLevelPython:
    def __ne__(self, other):
        return not self == other

class LowLevelPython:
    def __ne__(self, other):
        equal = self.__eq__(other)
        if equal is NotImplemented:
            return NotImplemented
        return not equal

def c_level():
    cl = CLevel()
    return lambda: cl != cl

def high_level_python():
    hlp = HighLevelPython()
    return lambda: hlp != hlp

def low_level_python():
    llp = LowLevelPython()
    return lambda: llp != llp
```

I think these performance numbers speak for themselves:

```
>>> import timeit
>>> min(timeit.repeat(c_level()))
0.09377292497083545
>>> min(timeit.repeat(high_level_python()))
0.2654011140111834
>>> min(timeit.repeat(low_level_python()))
0.3378178110579029
```

This makes sense when you consider that `low_level_python` is doing logic in Python that would otherwise be handled on the C level.

### Response to some critics

Another answerer writes:

> Aaron Hall’s implementation `not self == other` of the `__ne__` method is incorrect as it can never return `NotImplemented` (`not NotImplemented` is `False`) and therefore the `__ne__` method that has priority can never fall back on the `__ne__` method that does not have priority.

Having `__ne__` never return `NotImplemented` does not make it incorrect. Instead, we handle prioritization with `NotImplemented` via the check for equality with `==`. Assuming `==` is correctly implemented, we're done.

> `not self == other` used to be the default Python 3 implementation of the `__ne__` method but it was a bug and it was corrected in Python 3.4 on January 2015, as ShadowRanger noticed (see issue #21408).

Well, let's explain this.

As noted earlier, Python 3 by default handles `__ne__` by first checking if `self.__eq__(other)` returns `NotImplemented` (a singleton) - which should be checked for with `is` and returned if so, else it should return the inverse. Here is that logic written as a class mixin:

```
class CStyle__ne__:
    """Mixin that provides __ne__ functionality equivalent to 
    the builtin functionality
    """
    def __ne__(self, other):
        equal = self.__eq__(other)
        if equal is NotImplemented:
            return NotImplemented
        return not equal
```

This is necessary for correctness for C level Python API, and it was introduced in Python 3, making

- [the `__ne__` methods in this patch](https://bugs.python.org/file37837/method-not-operator-2.patch) to close [Issue 21408](https://bugs.python.org/issue21408) and
- [the `__ne__` methods in the follow-on cleanup removed here](https://hg.python.org/cpython/rev/3603bae63c13)

redundant. All relevant `__ne__` methods were removed, including ones implementing their own check as well as ones that delegate to `__eq__` directly or via `==` - and `==` was the most common way of doing so.

#### Is Symmetry Important?

Our persistent critic provides a pathological example to make the case for handling `NotImplemented` in `__ne__`, valuing symmetry above all else. Let's steel-man the argument with a clear example:

```py
class B:
    """
    this class has no __eq__ implementation, but asserts 
    any instance is not equal to any other object
    """
    def __ne__(self, other):
        return True

class A:
    "This class asserts instances are equivalent to all other objects"
    def __eq__(self, other):
        return True

>>> A() == B(), B() == A(), A() != B(), B() != A()
(True, True, False, True)
```

So, by this logic, in order to maintain symmetry, we need to write the complicated `__ne__`, regardless of Python version.

```py
class B:
    def __ne__(self, other):
        return True

class A:
    def __eq__(self, other):
        return True
    def __ne__(self, other):
        result = other.__eq__(self)
        if result is NotImplemented:
            return NotImplemented
        return not result

>>> A() == B(), B() == A(), A() != B(), B() != A()
(True, True, True, True)
```

Apparently we should give no mind that these instances are both equal and not equal.

***I propose that symmetry is less important than the presumption of sensible code and following the advice of the documentation.***

However, if A had a sensible implementation of `__eq__`, then we could still follow my direction here and we would still have symmetry:

```py
class B:
    def __ne__(self, other):
        return True

class A:
    def __eq__(self, other):
        return False         # <- this boolean changed... 

>>> A() == B(), B() == A(), A() != B(), B() != A()
(False, False, True, True)
```

### Conclusion

For Python 2 compatible code, use `==` to implement `__ne__`. It is more:

- correct
- simple
- performant

In Python 3 only, use the low-level negation on the C level - it is even *more* simple and performant (though the programmer is responsible for determining that it is *correct*).

Again, do *not* write low-level logic in high level Python.

Comment: Excellent examples!  Part of the surprise is that the order of the operands _doesn't matter at all_, unlike some magic methods with their "right-side" reflections.  To re-iterate the part that I missed (and which cost me a lot of time):  The rich comparison method of the _subclass_ is tried first, regardless of whether the code has the superclass or the subclass on the left of the operator.  This is why your `a1 != c2` returned `False` --- it didn't run `a1.__ne__`, but `c2.__ne__`, which negated the _mixin's_ `__eq__` method.  Since `NotImplemented` is truthy, `not NotImplemented` is `False`.

Comment: Your recent updates do successfully demonstrate the performance advantage of `not (self == other)`, but no one is arguing it isn't fast (well, faster than any other option on Py2 anyway). The problem is it's *wrong* in some cases; Python itself used to do `not (self == other)`, but changed because [it was incorrect in the presence of arbitrary subclasses](https://bugs.python.org/issue21408). Fastest to the wrong answer is still *wrong*.

Comment: @ShadowRanger I have provided example code that demonstrates correct behavior given a valid implementation of `__eq__`. The burden of proof is on you to provide example code that demonstrates that `not ==` returns an invalid result for some (any possible) correct implementation of `__eq__`.

Comment: @AaronHall: Simplest example isn't actually subclass related. It's failure to interoperate with "weird" classes, say, a class for which both `__eq__` and `__ne__` return `False` unconditionally. In general, flipping the order of two instances in a `==`/`!=` comparison should not change the result, but for your implementation, since the `__ne__` of the `Incomparable` class is never invoked, and the `__eq__` of your class returns `NotImplemented`, the `__eq__` of `Incomparable` is invoked, then reversed, making the result `True` *only* when your class is one the left, not on the right.

Comment: I can't come up with a subclass related one right now (I might be mixing up your implementation with the other bad implementation, `return not self.__eq__(other)`; I think yours might be okay for arbitrary subclasses). But [here's an example of the asymmetry problem](https://tio.run/##jZC9CoMwEID3PMV1iyAdOhYcdChk6dRdUj2pEC82iUOf3ib@QJRSvCEhfHf33aX/uJemyzhWSloL@ZWBjxobKEt8lyW3qJoUdDKDEG0DpB20tiXrJFXIdQp5lBDCoBsMwV070fUKOySHNdvRhxkw8hH@9C3JwRkgZBloxuZ5C76K/7eAbKo9L0vpZN/dhLX8YXcjAyqLk9usTkGV7npp5FPhge9aBDfpGx1eds5mws8d63jCetOS4zlPwj@IFES4/TMmp4WcNqTY1hRbEtUEMo5f) mentioned in my last comment.

Comment: The specific example is kind of unimportant really. The problem is that, in your implementation, the behavior of your `__ne__` delegates to `__eq__` (of both sides if necessary), but it *never* falls back to the `__ne__` of the other side even when both `__eq__` "give up". The correct `__ne__` delegates to its *own* `__eq__`, but if that returns `NotImplemented`, it falls back to go to the other side's `__ne__`, rather than inverting the other side's `__eq__` (since the other side may not have explicitly opt-ed in to delegating to `__eq__`, and you shouldn't be making that decision for it).

Comment: I'm going to be updating my answer in a day or two, but I find your comparison example pathological *and* unrealistic - it may be that the right thing for `__eq__` to do is raise an exception. I really think you need to find a non-pathological subclass example.

Comment: @AaronHall: On reexamining this today, I don't *think* your implementation is problematic for subclasses normally (it would be extremely convoluted to make it break, and the subclass, assumed to have full knowledge of the parent, should be able to avoid it). But I just gave a non-convoluted example in my answer. The non-pathological case is SQLAlchemy's ORM, where neither `__eq__` nor `__ne__` returns either `True` or `False`, but rather a proxy object (that happens to be "truthy"). Incorrectly implementing `__ne__` means order matters for the comparison (you only get a proxy in one ordering).

Comment: To be clear, in 99% (or maybe 99.999%) of cases, your solution is fine, and (obviously) faster. But since you don't have control over the cases where it *isn't* fine, as a library writer whose code may be used by others (read: anything but simple one-off scripts and modules solely for personal use), you have to use the correct implementation to adhere to the general contract for operator overloading and work with whatever other code you might encounter. Luckily, on Py3, none of this matters, since you can omit `__ne__` entirely. A year from now, Py2 will be dead and we ignore this. :-)

Comment: AaronHall, you might be interested in my updated answer which uses I think a stronger argument than @ShadowRanger’s `Incomparable` class argument since this class breaks the *complement* relationship between the `!=` and `==` operators and therefore might be considered a "pathological » example like you put it. And I agree that you are right when you point out that @ShadowRanger’s SQLAlchemy argument might be considered irrelevant since it is in non-Boolean context.

Answer (score 13):

Just for the record, a canonically correct and cross Py2/Py3 portable `__ne__` would look like:

```
import sys

class ...:
    ...
    def __eq__(self, other):
        ...

    if sys.version_info[0] == 2:
        def __ne__(self, other):
            equal = self.__eq__(other)
            return equal if equal is NotImplemented else not equal
```

This works with any `__eq__` you might define:

- Unlike `not (self == other)`, doesn't interfere with in some annoying/complex cases involving comparisons where one of the classes involved doesn't imply that the result of `__ne__` is the same as the result of `not` on `__eq__` (e.g. SQLAlchemy's ORM, where both `__eq__` and `__ne__` return special proxy objects, not `True` or `False`, and trying to `not` the result of `__eq__` would return `False`, rather than the correct proxy object).
- Unlike `not self.__eq__(other)`, this correctly delegates to the `__ne__` of the other instance when `self.__eq__` returns `NotImplemented` (`not self.__eq__(other)` would be extra wrong, because `NotImplemented` is truthy, so when `__eq__` didn't know how to perform the comparison, `__ne__` would return `False`, implying that the two objects were equal when in fact the only object asked had no idea, which would imply a default of not equal)

If your `__eq__` doesn't use `NotImplemented` returns, this works (with meaningless overhead), if it does use `NotImplemented` sometimes, this handles it properly. And the Python version check means that if the class is `import`-ed in Python 3, `__ne__` is left undefined, allowing Python's native, efficient fallback [`__ne__` implementation (a C version of the above)](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.5/Objects/typeobject.c#l3508) to take over.

---

## Why this is needed

### Python overloading rules

The explanation of why you do this instead of other solutions is somewhat arcane. Python has a couple general rules about overloading operators, and comparison operators in particular:

1. (Applies to all operators) When running `LHS OP RHS`, try `LHS.__op__(RHS)`, and if that returns `NotImplemented`, try `RHS.__rop__(LHS)`. Exception: If `RHS` is a subclass of `LHS`'s class, then test `RHS.__rop__(LHS)` *first*. In the case of comparison operators, `__eq__` and `__ne__` are their own "rop"s (so the test order for `__ne__` is `LHS.__ne__(RHS)`, then `RHS.__ne__(LHS)`, reversed if `RHS` is a subclass of `LHS`'s class)
2. Aside from the idea of the "swapped" operator, there is no implied relationship between the operators. Even for instance of the same class, `LHS.__eq__(RHS)` returning `True` does not imply `LHS.__ne__(RHS)` returns `False` (in fact, the operators aren't even required to return boolean values; ORMs like SQLAlchemy intentionally do not, allowing for a more expressive query syntax). As of Python 3, the default `__ne__` implementation behaves this way, but it's not contractual; you can override `__ne__` in ways that aren't strict opposites of `__eq__`.

### How this applies to overloading comparators

So when you overload an operator, you have two jobs:

1. If you know how to implement the operation yourself, do so, using *only* your own knowledge of how to do the comparison (never delegate, implicitly or explicitly, to the other side of the operation; doing so risks incorrectness and/or infinite recursion, depending on how you do it)
2. If you *don't* know how to implement the operation yourself, *always* return `NotImplemented`, so Python can delegate to the other operand's implementation

### The problem with `not self.__eq__(other)`

```
def __ne__(self, other):
    return not self.__eq__(other)
```

never delegates to the other side (and is incorrect if `__eq__` properly returns `NotImplemented`). When `self.__eq__(other)` returns `NotImplemented` (which is "truthy"), you silently return `False`, so `A() != something_A_knows_nothing_about` returns `False`, when it should have checked if `something_A_knows_nothing_about` knew how to compare to instances of `A`, and if it doesn't, it should have returned `True` (since if neither side knows how to compare to the other, they're considered not equal to one another). If `A.__eq__` is incorrectly implemented (returning `False` instead of `NotImplemented` when it doesn't recognize the other side), then this is "correct" from `A`'s perspective, returning `True` (since `A` doesn't think it's equal, so it's not equal), but it might be wrong from `something_A_knows_nothing_about`'s perspective, since it never even asked `something_A_knows_nothing_about`; `A() != something_A_knows_nothing_about` ends up `True`, but `something_A_knows_nothing_about != A()` could `False`, or any other return value.

### The problem with `not self == other`

```
def __ne__(self, other):
    return not self == other
```

is more subtle. It's going to be correct for 99% of classes, including all classes for which `__ne__` is the logical inverse of `__eq__`. But `not self == other` breaks both of the rules mentioned above, which means for classes where `__ne__` *isn't* the logical inverse of `__eq__`, the results are once again non-symmetric, because one of the operands is never asked if it can implement `__ne__` at all, even if the other operand can't. The simplest example is a weirdo class which returns `False` for *all* comparisons, so `A() == Incomparable()` and `A() != Incomparable()` both return `False`. With a correct implementation of `A.__ne__` (one which returns `NotImplemented` when it doesn't know how to do the comparison), the relationship is symmetric; `A() != Incomparable()` and `Incomparable() != A()` agree on the outcome (because in the former case, `A.__ne__` returns `NotImplemented`, then `Incomparable.__ne__` returns `False`, while in the latter, `Incomparable.__ne__` returns `False` directly). But when `A.__ne__` is implemented as `return not self == other`, `A() != Incomparable()` returns `True` (because `A.__eq__` returns, not `NotImplemented`, then `Incomparable.__eq__` returns `False`, and `A.__ne__` inverts that to `True`), while `Incomparable() != A()` returns `False.`

You can see an example of this in action [here](https://tio.run/##tVI7a8MwEN79Ky5kqAOmQ8dABruk4KVTd6PY50RwkRzpQsivd09@gO02ECjVIom773Gf1Nz5ZM1b25akvId0G4GsNewvV0XAFhQRWD6hA208K1OiB1tD2vVVWENR4KUoYo9UJ33npicJS9dgLIP2IzjuOhJIJ01hOeSrM/BpOT83hGc0jFW0qH65K050DT7UXUNuSusclkx3aSc8KhbnMpBmGeBmBt9QWyJ7wwq06OpSh/7DHYRvQtYH4HWFL34Eymh8Ugy10uSXTsPQwRnsdj04ivqAs2cDzv4YcPbfAb//Eq81cv2RcTLQa3N8pL8OqJEnnEVumXpw8zh12HWBvw5p9X6X84U@Yeg2v/ACSB67MKU8Plf4RedGOXUg3D73IoPUhxK657KcIaJcJpnKxpuocdpwnMab8J3yBPKwy3VaWQ2V1aySzTHZvDLBhErbfgM).

Obviously, a class that always returns `False` for both `__eq__` and `__ne__` is a little strange. But as mentioned before, `__eq__` and `__ne__` don't even need to return `True`/`False`; the SQLAlchemy ORM has classes with comparators that returns a special proxy object for query building, not `True`/`False` at all (they're "truthy" if evaluated in a boolean context, but they're never supposed to be evaluated in such a context).

By failing to overload `__ne__` properly, you *will* break classes of that sort, as the code:

```
 results = session.query(MyTable).filter(MyTable.fieldname != MyClassWithBadNE())
```

will work (assuming SQLAlchemy knows how to insert `MyClassWithBadNE` into a SQL string at all; this can be done with type adapters without `MyClassWithBadNE` having to cooperate at all), passing the expected proxy object to `filter`, while:

```
 results = session.query(MyTable).filter(MyClassWithBadNE() != MyTable.fieldname)
```

will end up passing `filter` a plain `False`, because `self == other` returns a proxy object, and `not self == other` just converts the truthy proxy object to `False`. Hopefully, `filter` throws an exception on being handled invalid arguments like `False`. While I'm sure many will argue that `MyTable.fieldname` *should* be consistently on the left hand side of the comparison, the fact remains that there is no programmatic reason to enforce this in the general case, and a correct generic `__ne__` will work either way, while `return not self == other` only works in one arrangement.

Comment: The only correct, complete and honest (sorry @AaronHall) answer. This should be the accepted answer.

Comment: You might be interested by my updated answer which uses I think a stronger argument than your `Incomparable` class since this class breaks the *complement* relationship between the `!=` and `==` operators and therefore might be considered an invalid or "pathological" example like @AaronHall put it. And I admit that @AaronHall has a point when he pointed out that your SQLAlchemy argument might be considered irrelevant since it is in non-Boolean context. (Your arguments are still very interesting and well thought.)

Comment: +1. For an existing project that forgot to implement `__ne__` for Python 2 a long time ago, I am just looking for a `__ne__` shim that best mimics the behavior of Python 3-without-`__ne__`, to prevent regressions for existing Python 3 users, even under pathological circumstances. I tested @AaronHall's solution against several other classes, some admittedly convoluted, but it simply sometimes does not return the same as Python 3-without-`__ne__`. In contrast, this @ShadowRanger/@Maggyero solution always behaves exactly as Python 3-without-`__ne__`, no matter what crazy stuff I throw at it.

Answer (score 7):

### Correct implementation of `__ne__`

@ShadowRanger’s implementation of the special method `__ne__` is the correct one:

```py
def __ne__(self, other):
    result = self.__eq__(other)
    if result is not NotImplemented:
        return not result
    return NotImplemented
```

It also happens to be the default implementation of the special method `__ne__` [since Python 3.4](https://github.com/python/cpython/commit/f4b7a02e932671c6e54e6b48340173cc859ab4c0), as stated in the [Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__ne__):

> By default, `__ne__()` delegates to `__eq__()` and inverts the result unless it is `NotImplemented`.

Also note that returning the value `NotImplemented` for unsupported operands is not specific to the special method `__ne__`. In fact, **all the special comparison methods<sup>1</sup> and special numeric methods<sup>2</sup> should return the value `NotImplemented` for unsupported operands**, as specified in the [Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#the-standard-type-hierarchy):

> NotImplemented
>
> This type has a single value. There is a single object with this value. This object is accessed through the built-in name `NotImplemented`. Numeric methods and rich comparison methods should return this value if they do not implement the operation for the operands provided. (The interpreter will then try the reflected operation, or some other fallback, depending on the operator.) Its truth value is true.

An example for the special numeric methods is given in the [Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/numbers.html#implementing-the-arithmetic-operations):

```py
class MyIntegral(Integral):

    def __add__(self, other):
        if isinstance(other, MyIntegral):
            return do_my_adding_stuff(self, other)
        elif isinstance(other, OtherTypeIKnowAbout):
            return do_my_other_adding_stuff(self, other)
        else:
            return NotImplemented

    def __radd__(self, other):
        if isinstance(other, MyIntegral):
            return do_my_adding_stuff(other, self)
        elif isinstance(other, OtherTypeIKnowAbout):
            return do_my_other_adding_stuff(other, self)
        elif isinstance(other, Integral):
            return int(other) + int(self)
        elif isinstance(other, Real):
            return float(other) + float(self)
        elif isinstance(other, Complex):
            return complex(other) + complex(self)
        else:
            return NotImplemented
```

---

<sup>1</sup> The special comparison methods: `__lt__`, `__le__`, `__eq__`, `__ne__`, `__gt__` and `__ge__`.

<sup>2</sup> The special numeric methods: `__add__`, `__sub__`, `__mul__`, `__matmul__`, `__truediv__`, `__floordiv__`, `__mod__`, `__divmod__`, `__pow__`, `__lshift__`, `__rshift__`, `__and__`, `__xor__`, `__or__` and their `__r*__` reflected and `__i*__` in-place counterparts.

### Incorrect implementation of `__ne__` #1

@Falmarri’s implementation of the special method `__ne__` is incorrect:

```py
def __ne__(self, other):
    return not self.__eq__(other)
```

The problem with this implementation is that it does not fall back on the special method `__ne__` of the other operand as it never returns the value `NotImplemented` (the expression `not self.__eq__(other)` evaluates to the value `True` or `False`, including when its subexpression `self.__eq__(other)` evaluates to the value `NotImplemented` since the expression `bool(NotImplemented)` evaluates to the value `True`). The Boolean evaluation of the value `NotImplemented` breaks the *complement* relationship between the comparison operators `!=` and `==`:

```py
class Correct:

    def __ne__(self, other):
        result = self.__eq__(other)
        if result is not NotImplemented:
            return not result
        return NotImplemented


class Incorrect:

    def __ne__(self, other):
        return not self.__eq__(other)


x, y = Correct(), Correct()
assert (x != y) is not (x == y)

x, y = Incorrect(), Incorrect()
assert (x != y) is not (x == y)  # AssertionError
```

### Incorrect implementation of `__ne__` #2

@AaronHall’s implementation of the special method `__ne__` is also incorrect:

```py
def __ne__(self, other):
    return not self == other
```

The problem with this implementation is that it directly falls back on the special method `__eq__` of the other operand, bypassing the special method `__ne__` of the other operand as it never returns the value `NotImplemented` (the expression `not self == other` falls back on the special method `__eq__` of the other operand and evaluates to the value `True` or `False`). Bypassing a method is incorrect because that method may have [*side effects*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Side_effect_(computer_science)) like updating the state of the object:

```py
class Correct:

    def __init__(self):
        self.state = False

    def __ne__(self, other):
        self.state = True
        result = self.__eq__(other)
        if result is not NotImplemented:
            return not result
        return NotImplemented


class Incorrect:

    def __init__(self):
        self.state = False

    def __ne__(self, other):
        self.state = True
        return not self == other


x, y = Correct(), Correct()
assert x != y
assert x.state == y.state

x, y = Incorrect(), Incorrect()
assert x != y
assert x.state == y.state  # AssertionError
```

### Understanding comparison operations

In mathematics, a [*binary relation*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_relation) *R* over a set *X* is a set of ordered pairs (*x*, *y*) in *X*<sup>2</sup>. The statement (*x*, *y*) in *R* reads ‘*x* is *R*-related to *y*’ and is denoted by *xRy*.

Properties of a binary relation *R* over a set *X*:

- *R* is [*reflexive*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflexive_relation) when for all *x* in *X*, *xRx*.
- *R* is [*irreflexive*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflexive_relation#Related_terms) (also called *strict*) when for all *x* in *X*, not *xRx*.
- *R* is [*symmetric*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_relation) when for all *x* and *y* in *X*, if *xRy* then *yRx*.
- *R* is [*antisymmetric*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antisymmetric_relation) when for all *x* and *y* in *X*, if *xRy* and *yRx* then *x* = *y*.
- *R* is [*transitive*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transitive_relation) when for all *x*, *y* and *z* in *X*, if *xRy* and *yRz* then *xRz*.
- *R* is [*connex*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connex_relation) (also called *total*) when for all *x* and *y* in *X*, *xRy* or *yRx*.
- *R* is an [*equivalence relation*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_relation) when *R* is reflexive, symmetric and transitive.
  For example, =. However ≠ is only symmetric.
- *R* is an [*order relation*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partially_ordered_set) when *R* is reflexive, antisymmetric and transitive.
  For example, ≤ and ≥.
- *R* is a [*strict order relation*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partially_ordered_set#Strict_and_non-strict_partial_orders) when *R* is irreflexive, antisymmetric and transitive.
  For example, < and >. However ≠ is only irreflexive.

Operations on two binary relations *R* and *S* over a set *X*:

- The [*converse*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_relation#Converse) of *R* is the binary relation *R*<sup>T</sup> = {(*y*, *x*) | *xRy*} over *X*.
- The [*complement*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_relation#Complement) of *R* is the binary relation ¬*R* = {(*x*, *y*) | not *xRy*} over *X*.
- The [*union*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_relation#Union) of *R* and *S* is the binary relation *R* ∪ *S* = {(*x*, *y*) | *xRy* or *xSy*} over *X*.

Relationships between comparison relations that are always valid:

- 2 complementary relationships: = and ≠ are each other’s complement;
- 6 converse relationships: = is the converse of itself, ≠ is the converse of itself, < and > are each other’s converse, and ≤ and ≥ are each other’s converse;
- 2 union relationships: ≤ is the union of < and =, and ≥ is the union of > and =.

Relationships between comparison relations that are only valid for *connex* order relations:

- 4 complementary relationships: < and ≥ are each other’s complement, and > and ≤ are each other’s complement.

So to correctly implement in Python the comparison operators `==`, `!=`, `<`, `>`, `<=`, and `>=` corresponding to the comparison relations =, ≠, <, >, ≤, and ≥, all the above mathematical properties and relationships should hold.

A comparison operation `x operator y` calls the special comparison method `__operator__` of the class of one of its operands:

```py
class X:

    def __operator__(self, other):
        # implementation
```

Since *R* is *reflexive* implies *xRx*, a reflexive comparison operation `x operator y` (`x == y`, `x <= y` and `x >= y`) or reflexive special comparison method call `x.__operator__(y)` (`x.__eq__(y)`, `x.__le__(y)` and `x.__ge__(y)`) should evaluate to the value `True` if `x` and `y` are identical, that is if the expression `x is y` evaluates to `True`. Since *R* is *irreflexive* implies not *xRx*, an irreflexive comparison operation `x operator y` (`x != y`, `x < y` and `x > y`) or irreflexive special comparison method call `x.__operator__(y)` (`x.__ne__(y)`, `x.__lt__(y)` and `x.__gt__(y)`) should evaluate to the value `False` if `x` and `y` are identical, that is if the expression `x is y` evaluates to `True`. The reflexive property is considered by Python for the comparison operator `==` and associated special comparison method `__eq__` but [surprisingly not considered](https://discuss.python.org/t/add-missing-default-implementations-of-le-and-ge/5327/18?u=maggyero) for the comparison operators `<=` and `>=` and associated special comparison methods `__le__` and `__ge__`, and the irreflexive property is considered by Python for the comparison operator `!=` and associated special comparison method `__ne__` but [surprisingly not considered](https://discuss.python.org/t/add-missing-default-implementations-of-le-and-ge/5327/18?u=maggyero) for the comparison operators `<` and `>` and associated special comparison methods `__lt__` and `__gt__`. The ignored comparison operators instead raise the exception `TypeError` (and associated special comparison methods instead return the value `NotImplemented`), as explained in the [Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#value-comparisons):

> The default behavior for equality comparison (`==` and `!=`) is based
> on the identity of the objects. Hence, equality comparison of
> instances with the same identity results in equality, and equality
> comparison of instances with different identities results in
> inequality. A motivation for this default behavior is the desire that
> all objects should be reflexive (i.e. `x is y` implies `x == y`).
>
> A default order comparison (`<`, `>`, `<=`, and `>=`) is not provided;
> an attempt raises `TypeError`. A motivation for this default behavior
> is the lack of a similar invariant as for equality. *[This is incorrect since `<=` and `>=` are reflexive like `==`, and `<` and `>` are irreflexive like `!=`.]*

The class `object` provides the default implementations of the special comparison methods which are inherited by all its subclasses, as explained in the [Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__lt__):

> `object.__lt__(self, other)`
> `object.__le__(self, other)`
> `object.__eq__(self, other)`
> `object.__ne__(self, other)`
> `object.__gt__(self, other)`
> `object.__ge__(self, other)`
>
> These are the so-called “rich comparison” methods. The correspondence
> between operator symbols and method names is as follows: `x<y` calls
> `x.__lt__(y)`, `x<=y` calls `x.__le__(y)`, `x==y` calls `x.__eq__(y)`,
> `x!=y` calls `x.__ne__(y)`, `x>y` calls `x.__gt__(y)`, and `x>=y`
> calls `x.__ge__(y)`.
>
> A rich comparison method may return the singleton `NotImplemented` if
> it does not implement the operation for a given pair of arguments.
>
> *[…]*
>
> There are no swapped-argument versions of these methods (to be used
> when the left argument does not support the operation but the right
> argument does); rather, `__lt__()` and `__gt__()` are each other’s
> reflection, `__le__()` and `__ge__()` are each other’s reflection, and
> `__eq__()` and `__ne__()` are their own reflection. If the operands
> are of different types, and right operand’s type is a direct or
> indirect subclass of the left operand’s type, the reflected method of
> the right operand has priority, otherwise the left operand’s method
> has priority. Virtual subclassing is not considered.

Since *R* = (*R*<sup>T</sup>)<sup>T</sup>, a comparison *xRy* is equivalent to the *converse* comparison *yR*<sup>T</sup>*x* (informally named ‘reflected’ in the Python documentation). So there are two ways to compute the result of a comparison operation `x operator y`: calling either `x.__operator__(y)` or `y.__operatorT__(x)`. Python uses the following computing strategy:

1. It calls `x.__operator__(y)` unless the right operand’s class is a descendant of the left operand’s class, in which case it calls `y.__operatorT__(x)` (*allowing classes to override their ancestors’ converse special comparison method*).
2. If the operands `x` and `y` are unsupported (indicated by the return value `NotImplemented`), it calls the converse special comparison method as a *1st fallback*.
3. If the operands `x` and `y` are unsupported (indicated by the return value `NotImplemented`), it raises the exception `TypeError` except for the comparison operators `==` and `!=` for which it compares respectively the identity and non-identity of the operands `x` and `y` as a *2nd fallback* (leveraging the reflexivity property of `==` and irreflexivity property of `!=`).
4. It returns the result.

In CPython [this is implemented in C code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.8.6/Objects/object.c#L707-L756), which can be translated into Python code (with the names `eq` for `==`, `ne` for `!=`, `lt` for `<`, `gt` for `>`, `le` for `<=` and `ge` for `>=`):

```py
def eq(left, right):
    if type(left) != type(right) and isinstance(right, type(left)):
        result = right.__eq__(left)
        if result is NotImplemented:
            result = left.__eq__(right)
    else:
        result = left.__eq__(right)
        if result is NotImplemented:
            result = right.__eq__(left)
    if result is NotImplemented:
        result = left is right
    return result
```

```py
def ne(left, right):
    if type(left) != type(right) and isinstance(right, type(left)):
        result = right.__ne__(left)
        if result is NotImplemented:
            result = left.__ne__(right)
    else:
        result = left.__ne__(right)
        if result is NotImplemented:
            result = right.__ne__(left)
    if result is NotImplemented:
        result = left is not right
    return result
```

```py
def lt(left, right):
    if type(left) != type(right) and isinstance(right, type(left)):
        result = right.__gt__(left)
        if result is NotImplemented:
            result = left.__lt__(right)
    else:
        result = left.__lt__(right)
        if result is NotImplemented:
            result = right.__gt__(left)
    if result is NotImplemented:
        raise TypeError(
            f"'<' not supported between instances of '{type(left).__name__}' "
            f"and '{type(right).__name__}'"
        )
    return result
```

```py
def gt(left, right):
    if type(left) != type(right) and isinstance(right, type(left)):
        result = right.__lt__(left)
        if result is NotImplemented:
            result = left.__gt__(right)
    else:
        result = left.__gt__(right)
        if result is NotImplemented:
            result = right.__lt__(left)
    if result is NotImplemented:
        raise TypeError(
            f"'>' not supported between instances of '{type(left).__name__}' "
            f"and '{type(right).__name__}'"
        )
    return result
```

```py
def le(left, right):
    if type(left) != type(right) and isinstance(right, type(left)):
        result = right.__ge__(left)
        if result is NotImplemented:
            result = left.__le__(right)
    else:
        result = left.__le__(right)
        if result is NotImplemented:
            result = right.__ge__(left)
    if result is NotImplemented:
        raise TypeError(
            f"'<=' not supported between instances of '{type(left).__name__}' "
            f"and '{type(right).__name__}'"
        )
    return result
```

```py
def ge(left, right):
    if type(left) != type(right) and isinstance(right, type(left)):
        result = right.__le__(left)
        if result is NotImplemented:
            result = left.__ge__(right)
    else:
        result = left.__ge__(right)
        if result is NotImplemented:
            result = right.__le__(left)
    if result is NotImplemented:
        raise TypeError(
            f"'>=' not supported between instances of '{type(left).__name__}' "
            f"and '{type(right).__name__}'"
        )
    return result
```

Since *R* = ¬(¬*R*), a comparison *xRy* is equivalent to the *complement* comparison ¬(*x*¬*Ry*). ≠ is the complement of =, so the special method `__ne__` is implemented in terms of the special method `__eq__` for supported operands by default, while the other special comparison methods are implemented independently by default (the fact that ≤ is the union of < and =, and ≥ is the union of > and = is [surprisingly not considered](https://discuss.python.org/t/add-missing-default-implementations-of-le-and-ge/5327/18?u=maggyero), which means that currently the special methods `__le__` and `__ge__` should be user implemented), as explained in the [Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__lt__):

> By default, `__ne__()` delegates to `__eq__()` and inverts the result
> unless it is `NotImplemented`. There are no other implied
> relationships among the comparison operators, for example, the truth
> of `(x<y or x==y)` does not imply `x<=y`.

In CPython [this is implemented in C code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.8.6/Objects/typeobject.c#L3837-L3883), which can be translated into Python code:

```py
def __eq__(self, other):
    return self is other or NotImplemented
```

```py
def __ne__(self, other):
    result = self.__eq__(other)
    if result is not NotImplemented:
        return not result
    return NotImplemented
```

```py
def __lt__(self, other):
    return NotImplemented
```

```py
def __gt__(self, other):
    return NotImplemented
```

```py
def __le__(self, other):
    return NotImplemented
```

```py
def __ge__(self, other):
    return NotImplemented
```

So by default:

- a comparison operation `x operator y` raises the exception `TypeError` except for the comparison operators `==` and `!=` for which it returns respectively the values `True` and `False` if the operands `x` and `y` are respectively identical and non-identical, and the values `False` and `True` otherwise;
- a special comparison method call `x.__operator__(y)` returns the value `NotImplemented` except for the special comparison methods `__eq__` and `__ne__` for which it returns respectively the values `True` and `False` if the operands `x` and `y` are respectively identical and non-identical, and the value `NotImplemented` otherwise.

Comment: To your last example: "Since this implementation fails to replicate the behavior of the default implementation of the `__ne__` method when the `__eq__` method returns NotImplemented, it is incorrect." - `A` defines unconditional equality. Thus, `A() == B()`. Thus `A() != B()` *should be False*, and it *is*. The examples given are pathological (i.e. `__ne__` should not return a string, and `__eq__` should not depend on `__ne__` - rather `__ne__` should depend on `__eq__`, which is the default expectation in Python 3). I'm still -1 on this answer until you can change my mind.

Comment: The final example has two classes, `B`, that returns a truthy string on all checks for `__ne__`, and `A` that returns `True` on all checks for `__eq__`. This is a ***pathological contradiction.*** Under such a contradiction, it would be best to raise an exception. Without knowledge of `B`, `A` is under no obligation to respect `B`'s implementation of `__ne__` for the purposes of symmetry. At that point in the example, how `A` implements `__ne__` is irrelevant to me. Please find a practical, non-pathological case to make your point. I have updated my answer to address you.

Comment: SQLAlchemy's use case is for a Domain Specific Language. If one is designing such a DSL, one may throw all the advice here out the window. To keep torturing this poor analogy, your example is expecting a plane to be flying backwards half the time, and mine only expects them to be flying forwards, and I think that's a reasonable design decision. I think the concern you are raising is unwarranted and backwards.