# Why does Python have an __ne__ operator method instead of just __eq__?

Tags: python, operator-overloading

The answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4352244/python-implementing-ne-operator-based-on-eq) gives a handwaving reference to cases where you'd want `__ne__` to return something other than just the logical inverse of `__eq__`, but I can't imagine any such case. Any examples?

Comment: At least for `>` and `<=` there are such cases. Namely `NaN < anything => false` and `NaN >= anything => false`. (Assuming python follows IEEE floating point logic)

Comment: Yep basically anything that doesn't have a [total order](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_ordering) can fall into that category. Now those things are kinda rare for obvious reasons, but they do exist. NaNs are a nice example.

Comment: But even for `NaN` it holds at least in python: `NaN != NaN => True`, `NaN == NaN => False`.

Comment: The fact that `equals` (`__eq__`) _may not_ return a `Boolean` type and that `not equals` (`__ne__`) _may not_ be the opposite of equals... defies all intuition. -- I accept it as the Python way. I guess it has its benefits as explained by the answers. Yet, for newcomers to the language, this is eerie.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

SQLAlchemy is a great example. For the uninitiated, SQLAlchemy is a ORM and uses Python expression to generate SQL statements. In a expression such as

```
meta.Session.query(model.Theme).filter(model.Theme.id == model.Vote.post_id)
```

the `model.Theme.id == model.VoteWarn.post_id` does not return a boolean, but a object that eventually produces a SQL query like `WHERE theme.id = vote.post_id`. The inverse would produce something like `WHERE theme.id <> vote.post_id` so both methods need to be defined.

Answer (score 30):

Some libraries do fancy things and don't return a bool from these operations. For example, with numpy:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> np.array([1,2,5,4,3,4,5,4,4])==4
array([False, False, False,  True, False,  True, False,  True,  True], dtype=bool)
>>> np.array([1,2,5,4,3,4,5,4,4])!=4
array([ True,  True,  True, False,  True, False,  True, False, False], dtype=bool)
```

When you compare an array to a single value or another array you get back an array of bools of the results of comparing the corresponding elements. You couldn't do this if `x!=y` was simply equivalent to `not (x==y)`.

Comment: I can't follow that. Considering that `not` is defined on an array of bools in the obvious way, we still don't need `neq` instead of `not equals`. But clearly there's a performance and possible memory advantage there.

Comment: While a good argument could be made for a `__not__` special method to override the `not` operator, this does not currently exist in Python.

Comment: Oh that's surprising.. yeah in that case it's not only a matter of performance. Thanks!

Comment: @Weeble Unary invert ([`__invert__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__invert__)) works: `~np.array([True, False])` -> `array([False,  True])`. Though I'm not sure if it was the same back in 2012.

Answer (score 8):

More generally, in [many valued logic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Many-valued_logic) systems, `equals` and `not equals` are not necessarily exact inverses of each other.

The obvious example is SQL where `True == True`, `False == False` and `Null != Null`. Although I don't know if there are any specific Python examples I can imagine it being implemented in places.

Comment: And in MYSQL, you can even have values that are `NULL` and `NOT NULL` at the same time!!!1! (I consider that a design bug of MySQL though)