# Python if not == vs if !=

Tags: python, if-statement, equality

What is the difference between these two lines of code:

```
if not x == 'val':
```

and

```
if x != 'val':
```

Is one more efficient than the other?

Would it be better to use

```
if x == 'val':
    pass
else:
```

Comment: The better is the one you can read, I doubt your program's bottleneck will be here

Comment: This question interests me in the "x not in list" and "not x in list" case

Comment: @SomethingSomething they are interpreted identically.

Comment: @SomethingSomething reference for my above comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/8738388/3001761

Comment: @jonrsharpe your link is about substrings. I thought about collections(list/dict/set). Anyway - makes sense, thank you!

Comment: @SomethingSomething it's the same for those, too; it's how the syntax is interpreted, it doesn't matter what the two operands are.

Comment: The `not x == 'val'` is somewhat slower to be parsed than the `x != 'val'`, but the time difference is beyond measurement. The actual execution time is equal.

Comment: Side note: You can scan your code with my plugin [`flake8-simplify`](https://pypi.org/project/flake8-simplify) for this pattern (SIM201) and others

Answer (score 241, accepted):

Using [`dis`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/dis.html) to look at the bytecode generated for the two versions:

**`not ==`**

```
  4           0 LOAD_FAST                0 (foo)
              3 LOAD_FAST                1 (bar)
              6 COMPARE_OP               2 (==)
              9 UNARY_NOT           
             10 RETURN_VALUE
```

**`!=`**

```
  4           0 LOAD_FAST                0 (foo)
              3 LOAD_FAST                1 (bar)
              6 COMPARE_OP               3 (!=)
              9 RETURN_VALUE
```

The latter has fewer operations, and is therefore likely to be slightly more efficient.

---

It was pointed out [in the commments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31026754/python-if-not-vs-if/31026976#comment50099324_31026976) (thanks, [@Quincunx](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1896169/quincunx)) that where you have `if foo != bar` vs. `if not foo == bar` the number of operations is exactly the same, it's just that the `COMPARE_OP` changes and `POP_JUMP_IF_TRUE` switches to `POP_JUMP_IF_FALSE`:

**`not ==`**:

```
  2           0 LOAD_FAST                0 (foo)
              3 LOAD_FAST                1 (bar)
              6 COMPARE_OP               2 (==)
              9 POP_JUMP_IF_TRUE        16
```

**`!=`**

```
  2           0 LOAD_FAST                0 (foo)
              3 LOAD_FAST                1 (bar)
              6 COMPARE_OP               3 (!=)
              9 POP_JUMP_IF_FALSE       16
```

In this case, unless there was a difference in the amount of work required for each comparison, it's unlikely you'd see any performance difference at all.

---

However, note that the two versions **won't always be logically identical**, as it will depend on the implementations of `__eq__` and `__ne__` for the objects in question. Per [the data model documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__lt__):

> There are no implied relationships among the comparison operators. The
>   truth of `x==y` does not imply that `x!=y` is false.

For example:

```
>>> class Dummy(object):
    def __eq__(self, other):
        return True
    def __ne__(self, other):
        return True


>>> not Dummy() == Dummy()
False
>>> Dummy() != Dummy()
True
```

---

Finally, and perhaps most importantly: in general, where the two *are* logically identical, **`x != y` is much more readable than `not x == y`**.

Comment: In practice, any class that has `__eq__` inconsistent with `__ne__` is flat-out broken.

Comment: Please note that it is not *always* true that `not x == y` has one more instruction. When I put the code into an `if`, it turned out that they both have the same number of instructions, just one had `POP_JUMP_IF_TRUE` and the other `POP_JUMP_IF_FALSE` (that was the only difference between them, other than using a different `COMPARE_OP`). When I compiled the code without the `if`s, I got what you got.

Comment: Another example where `==` and `!=` are not mutually exclusive is a SQL-like implementation involving `null` values.  In SQL `null` doesn't return `true` to `!=` compared to any other value, so python implementations of SQL interfaces may also have the same issue.

Comment: I'm beginning to wish I hadn't referred to the possible difference between `not ==` and `!=`, it seems to be the most interesting part of my answer! I don't think this is the place to dwell on if, why and when that makes sense - see e.g. [Why does Python have an `__ne__` operator method instead of just `__eq__`?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9452536/3001761)

Answer (score 32):

@jonrsharpe has an excellent explanation of what's going on. I thought I'd just show the difference in time when running each of the 3 options 10,000,000 times (enough for a slight difference to show).

Code used:

```
def a(x):
    if x != 'val':
        pass


def b(x):
    if not x == 'val':
        pass


def c(x):
    if x == 'val':
        pass
    else:
        pass


x = 1
for i in range(10000000):
    a(x)
    b(x)
    c(x)
```

And the cProfile profiler results:

[image]

So we can see that there is a very minute difference of ~0.7% between `if not x == 'val':` and `if x != 'val':`. Of these, `if x != 'val':` is the fastest.

However, most surprisingly, we can see that

```
if x == 'val':
        pass
    else:
```

is in fact the fastest, and beats `if x != 'val':` by ~0.3%. This isn't very readable, but I guess if you wanted a negligible performance improvement, one could go down this route.

Comment: I hope everyone knows not to _act_ on this information!  Making unreadable changes for a 0.3% improvement -- or even a 10% improvement -- is rarely a good idea, and this kind of improvement is very likely to be evanescent (and not [in a good way](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5anLPw0Efmo): very slight changes in the Python runtime could eliminate or even reverse any gain.

Comment: @Malvolio In addition, there are [different implementations](http://www.toptal.com/python/why-are-there-so-many-pythons) of Python.

Answer (score 7):

In the first one, Python has to execute one more operation than necessary (instead of just checking not equal to, it has to check if it is not true that it is equal, thus one more operation). It would be impossible to tell the difference from one execution, but if run many times, the second would be more efficient. Overall I would use the second one, but mathematically they are the same

Answer (score 6):

An additional note, since the other answers answered your question mostly correctly, is that if a class only defines `__eq__()` and not `__ne__()`, then your `COMPARE_OP (!=)` will run `__eq__()` and negate it. At that time, your third option is likely to be a tiny bit more efficient, but should only be considered if you NEED the speed, since it's difficult to understand quickly.

Answer (score 5):

```
>>> from dis import dis
>>> dis(compile('not 10 == 20', '', 'exec'))
  1           0 LOAD_CONST               0 (10)
              3 LOAD_CONST               1 (20)
              6 COMPARE_OP               2 (==)
              9 UNARY_NOT
             10 POP_TOP
             11 LOAD_CONST               2 (None)
             14 RETURN_VALUE
>>> dis(compile('10 != 20', '', 'exec'))
  1           0 LOAD_CONST               0 (10)
              3 LOAD_CONST               1 (20)
              6 COMPARE_OP               3 (!=)
              9 POP_TOP
             10 LOAD_CONST               2 (None)
             13 RETURN_VALUE
```

Here you can see that `not x == y` has one more instruction than `x != y`. So the performance difference will be very small in most cases unless you are doing millions of comparisons and even then this will likely not be the cause of a bottleneck.

Answer (score 3):

It's about your way of reading it. `not` operator is dynamic, that's why you are able to apply it in

```
if not x == 'val':
```

But `!=` could be read in a better context as an operator which does the opposite of what `==` does.

Comment: What do you mean *"`not` operator is dynamic"*?

Comment: @jonrsharpe I think he means that "not x" will call x.__bool__() [python 3 -- python 2 uses __nonzero__] and revert the result (see https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__bool__)

Answer (score 1):

I want to expand on my readability comment above.

Again, I completely agree with readability overriding other (performance-insignificant) concerns.

What I would like to point out is the brain interprets "positive" faster than it does "negative".  E.g., "stop" vs. "do not go" (a rather lousy example due to the difference in number of words).

So given a choice:

```
if a == b
    (do this)
else
    (do that)
```

is preferable to the functionally-equivalent:

```
if a != b
    (do that)
else
    (do this)
```

Less readability/understandability leads to more bugs.  Perhaps not in initial coding, but the (not as smart as you!) maintenance changes...

Comment: brain interprets "positive" faster than it does "negative"  is this from experience or have you read studies about this ? I'm just asking because depending on the code in (do this) or (do that), I find a != b easier to understand.