# Python infinite loop caused by or compound conditional but not when using not()

Tags: python

```
    test = ''

# This loop infinitely

    while test != 'O' or test != 'X':
        test = raw_input("Enter: ").upper()

# This works fine   

    while not(test == 'O' or test == 'X'):
        test = raw_input("Enter: ").upper()
```

What's the difference between putting `not` and using `!=` ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python != operation vs "is not"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2209755/python-operation-vs-is-not)

Comment: I would not consider that a duplicate. There is no use of `is` here.

Comment: Then it's a duplicate of this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31026754/python-if-not-vs-if/31026976 @KennethK.

Comment: Erm, I'd still say not. The big issue here is DeMorgan's, as identified by the answer below. Your proposal does not have a compound condition.

Comment: @quantik: Also not a duplicate.  The first question hinges on the `is` operator. The second asks for efficiency between the two, whereas the current question has a functionality problem.

Comment: OP, you want to know about "De Morgan's law".

Answer (score 17):

The problem is your conjunction: you failed to apply DeMorgan's laws properly.  You need to flip from `or` to `and` when you distribute the negation.

```
not(test == 'O' or test == 'X')
```

is equivalent to

```
test!= 'O' and test!= 'X'
```

Look at the logic of `test!= 'O' or test!= 'X'`: no matter what character you give to `test`, it will be *not* equal to at least one of the two test characters.  F0r `O`, the second clause is `True`; for `X`, the first is `True`; for any other character, *both* clauses are `True`.  To get past this, you'd need a character that was `X` and `O` at the same time.

We're not doing quantum variables in Python ... not yet, at least.  You'd have to write a new class with custom equality operators to make this work.

Answer (score 2):

... and if you go Pythonic all the way, you will write

```
while not test in ('O', 'X'):
```

or - even simpler

```
while not test in 'OX':
```

Comment: Yes, `not in` is better not only because of the Pythonicness, but also because this way you don't have to worry about precedence.