# How can Python methods and functions can change the values of object

Tags: python-3.x

This is something that has been in my mind since I knew about `.sort()` and `random.shuffle`.
although I couldn't find how `.sort()` works but I went through the `Lib\random.py` of course it was promising enough to be understood that how `random.shuffle(list_name)` shuffles the `list_name` itself but I found difficulty understanding how it worked there....

What I'm trying to understand:

```py
>>> lst = [-5, 2, 0, -2, -4, -3, 3, 4, -1, 5, 1]
>>> lst.sort() #How this changes the value of list???
>>> lst
[-5, -4, -3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>> random.shuffle(lst) #How does this function change the value of argument itself?
>>> lst
[-2, 2, -3, 1, 0, 5, -5, 4, 3, -1, -4]
```

A simple example will be helpful to understand:

```py
>>> a = [1,3,5,7,9]
>>> a.square()
>>> a
[1,9,25,49,81]
>>> b = [-2,-1,0,3,4]
>>> cube(b)
>>> b
[-8,-1,0,27,64]
```

How can I make the above code happen?

```py
def kyub(lst_):
    return [i**3 for i in lst_]
```

here the above `kyub()` *returns* a list what I am expecting is to `return` nothing but change the `lst_` itself.

*To sum up*

Assume we have a function `y = f(x)` which means for some value of `x=x0` there will be some `y=f(x0)` which is similar to `function = lambda x:f(x)` but I'm looking for a function `g(x)` that returns nothing(None) but changes the value of `x` itself.

Solution to the below problem can help me understand the logic behind this.

```py
>>> x_list = [value1, v2, v3, v4]
>>> print(x_list)   
[value1, v2, v3, v4]
>>> function(x_list)    
>>> print(x_list)
[output_1, output_2, output_3, output_4] #Note: I printed the value of x_list which now has changed. it's not what I'd printed it before.
```

Comment: Why _wouldn't_ they be able to? The whole point of methods is that they allow you to interact with an object's internal state. You can't do it with e.g. integers because they're _immutable_.

Comment: I personally always found the `random` API pretty annoying in that regard. As far as `lst.sort()` that's just a standard mutation. I generally avoid mutation at all costs, personally.

Comment: Where are those `.square()` and `cube()` methods from?

Comment: Sorry, just noticed your last question. So you're trying to implement both of those functionalities? Why? Generally one should *avoid* designing an API like that.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Yes, the word `immuatable` is enough 
but let's try something different `lst = [1,2,3,4]` and now let us assume there is a method `.square()` which if `lst.square()` will change the `lst = [1,4, 6, 16]` if it's possible can we do that?

Comment: Are you asking how to add methods to built-in types? Or maybe you want to implement your own Sequence with that method?

Comment: @ddejohn *Where are those .square() and cube() methods from?* by those last `.square() and `cube()` I meant, "Is it possible for us to write a method that changes the value of object itself or a function that can change the value of argument itself"

Comment: @jonrsharpe Yes you got me correct I want to understand how can I write me own `class` with some methods like `.square()` that will change the value of object itself....

Comment: What's what _most_ methods do, so I guess start with https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html.

Comment: @jonrsharpe thnx for the [python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html) but I have gone through this one also in fact I have this `pdf` downloaded.
but my bad couldn't find any example where I can see if there anyway I can do what I'm expecting in the question

Comment: Your examples in the question are not adding methods to your own classes, which is what you say you want to do, so this makes no sense. You can't (aside from hacks like https://pypi.org/project/forbiddenfruit/) add methods to the built-in types.

Comment: `a.square()` you can't, `cube(b)` is an easy function you should _try to write yourself_.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Yes, to return it is very easy what not easy is to get my argument updated >>>I updated my question....

Comment: You've written a function that returns a new list, _explicitly_. If that's not the behaviour you want, _write a different one_. SO is **not** a code-writing service, we're not here to replace basic tutorials and _practice_ - review basic list manipulation.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Yes your are right I understand that but I'm asking something different maybe I'm just not able explain it what I'm looking for which I'm sure that my question will not be going to `tutorials or practice` category...

Comment: It seems like you're asking how to update the values in a list, which is very much in the tutorial category (or would be, if we had one; it's **definitely** in the tutorial I've already linked you to). If that's the not the case you'll need to edit substantially to explain what you're really asking.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I have been in coding infact I understood your [beautiful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31026754/python-if-not-vs-if/31026976#31026976) of interesting question. 
I mean: I'm not asking somethin basics I can understand complicated things.

Comment: That's as may be, all we can go on is what's in the question.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I'll come up with more research and after going through the `Lib\modules.py` codes again till then we can keep this question here in the name of efforts done by you(plural/including others) in adding these valuable comments.

Answer (score 0):

Lists are mutable, meaning you can change their length, content, etc without creating a new object. So you can say

```
lst = []
lst.append(1)
```

and list will be [1].

Integers are immutable. So if you say

```
a = 5
a = a + 1
```

you aren't taking the 5 object and adding one, you are taking the value of a (5), adding 1, creating a new object, and assigning a to that object (actually python caches integers so its not exactly that but for this example it's fine.

If you want the same functionality, you have to assign a the new value

```
a = a.square()
```

Basically, you can do this to lists because thats how python is written. There are some functions on lists that change the current object, and some that return a copy of the list or values from the list. You just have to read the documentation to see how it handles the list

Comment: Okay thnx i got you,
but can we write a method `.square()` which will work as `lst = [2,6,9]` `lst.square() >>> [4, 36, 81]`
Now, is it possible to write a code for `.square()` method?

Comment: Sure its possible. The reason you can use sort() on list, is because list is a python object with the class method of sort(). You can either write a function that takes a list as an input and changes its contents (or returns a new list, squared) or you can write a new class that inherits from list and adds a squire method.  The most pythonic way to do it would be list = [i **2 for i in list]

Comment: Can you please provide me the snipped code?
but please I'm not expecting `function = lambda lst: [i**2 for i in lst]` which will give me `function([2,5,9]) >>> [4, 25, 81]`

Comment: What are you expecting? You want list objects to have a built in method you can call via a period? i.e. you want list.square() NOT square(list)?

Comment: @NikolaMarkovic if you just want to know how to assign a value into a list, that's covered by tutorials too: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html#lists

Comment: Both will be okay but instead of `return` they should change the value of `list_` itself.

like `random.shuffle(list_)` shuffles the `list_` instead of `returning` a shuffled `list_`

Comment: Just write a function that loops through the indexes in your list and assigns each index the squared value of the current value