# cleaner way to do a simple comparison using any?

Tags: python, testing

**some background**

I was setting up some tests for code submitted by users for an extremely simple data science test.

coding "challenges" would be structured like so in a Jupyter Notepook:

```
li1 = [2,4,3,-2,-1,5,10]
li2 = [5,4,-3,7,8,-5,10,9]
```

```
def findMedian(li):
    li.sort()

    # find the median of li...
    # your code below

    listlength = len(li)
    num = listlength//2
    if listlength % 2 == 0:
        return (li[num]+li[num-1])/2
    else:
        return li[num]
```

```
if findMedian(li1) == 3:
    print("1 is correct!")
else:
    print("1 is wrong")
if findMedian(li2) == 6:
    print("2 is correct!")
else:
    print("2 is wrong")
```

Now while this is nice enough I decided I should probably implement something like the following to truly check many cases.

```
from statistics import median
import random

x = [list(range(random.randint(1,50))) for i in range(1,100)]

print(not any([False if findMedian(i) == median(i) else True for i in x]))
```

the thing is, using `not any()` feels wrong, I've been doing it for a while and I feel like I have a little gap in my knowledge...

**question**

*Is there a cleaner way to express my comparisons?*

while
`not any([False if findMedian(i) == median(i) else True for i in x])`
does the job, is there a more efficient/pythonic way to express this?

Comment: A quick improvement is to use a generator expression instead of a list comprehension. You can't make as good of use of `any`'s early exit if you're strictly producing the data first (although that's unrelated). Also, using a ternary to evaluate to `True`/`False` is off. Just do `print(not any(findMedian(i) != median(i) for i in x))`

Comment: Oh I did not think of that. I would happily accept that edit as an answer, thanks for elaborating!

Comment: `False if findMedian(i) == median(i) else True` is a really convoluted way to write `findMedian(i) != median(i)`.

Comment: Also, the not-any-not formulation is a really convoluted way of writing `all(findMedian(i) == median(i) for i in x)`.

Comment: Gotta love De Morgan's Laws.

Comment: Thank you both for explaining that, my sense of logic definitely needs some work!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly, the list is unnecessary. Use a [generator expression](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-generator-expression) instead, which will be more efficient since it will allow [`any`/`all` to short-circuit](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17246413/4518341).

Next, `False if x == y else True` is the same as `not x == y`, and [for most objects](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9452536/4518341) including ints, `x != y`.

Lastly, thanks to [De Morgan's laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws), you can use `all(...)` instead of `not any(not ...)`.

```
all(findMedian(i) == median(i) for i in x)
```

Comment: Thanks for the HQ answer +  references!