# Why do the Python docs say I need to define __ne__ when I define __eq__?

Tags: python, operator-overloading, equality, inequality

According to the [Python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__ne__): "when defining `__eq__()`, one should also define `__ne__()` so that the operators will behave as expected".

However, it appears that Python computes `__ne__` as `not __eq__` automatically:

```
In [8]: class Test:
    def __eq__(self, other):
        print("calling __eq__")
   ...:         return isinstance(other, Test)
   ...:

In [9]: a = Test()

In [10]: b = Test()

In [11]: a == b
calling __eq__
Out[11]: True

In [12]: a != b
calling __eq__
Out[12]: False

In [13]: a == 1
calling __eq__
Out[13]: False

In [14]: a != 1
calling __eq__
Out[14]: True
```

So what's the point of defining `__ne__` if it's just going to be `return not self.__eq__(other)`? And furthermore, where is this behavior actually documented?

**EDIT**

Apparently it matters that I am using Python 3. In Python 2, I get

```
In [1]: class Test(object):
   ...:     def __eq__(self, other):
   ...:         print("calling __eq__")
   ...:         return isinstance(other, Test)
   ...:

In [2]: a = Test()

In [3]: b = Test()

In [4]: a == b
calling __eq__
Out[4]: True

In [5]: a != b
Out[5]: True

In [6]: a == 1
calling __eq__
Out[6]: False

In [7]: a != 1
Out[7]: True
```

But the docs I referenced are the Python 3 docs. Were they just not updated?

Comment: As a guess (and as such not an answer), you might want to define something e.g. `Rect() == Square() # True`, `Square() == Rect() # False` which is why they suggest you define both "so that the operators will behave as expected"

Comment: [Related question and a possible duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4352244/python-implementing-ne-operator-based-on-eq)

Comment: as far as I know these two methods are independent and overriding one of them doesn't mean overriding of other.

Comment: @frostnational that question (and none of its answers) seem to mention this behavior of Python 3

Comment: @oleg see my top example. Overriding `__eq__` *does* implicitly define `__ne__`, at least in Python 3.

Comment: It seems that if you do not define `__ne__` it uses `not` `__eq__`. But The truth of `x==y` does not imply that `x!=y` is false.
That's why you should define both.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Python 3 changed behaviour for the `==` case, see [Python 3, What's New](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.0.html#operators-and-special-methods):

> `!=` now returns the opposite of `==`, unless `==` returns `NotImplemented`.

It was deemed [a useful change](http://hg.python.org/cpython/annotate/834da52eb2a4/Objects/typeobject.c#l2317).

The fact that the documentation has not been updated is indeed a [long standing bug](http://bugs.python.org/issue4395).

*However*, as a comment on the report points out, if you inherit from a class that already has defined `__ne__`, overriding just `__eq__` is not enough and you'll also have to override the `__ne__` method.