# Python 2.7 What is compared if __ne__ is not defined

Tags: python-2.7

There is a magic method called `__ne__` in Python which is triggered on objects `!=` comparison.

**Example:**

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self, a):
        self.a = a

    def __ne__(self, other):
        return self.a != other.a

A(3) != A(3) # produces False
A(3) != A(2) # produces True
```

**The Question:**

What happens under the hood if `__ne__` is not defined?

*Note:* In python 3.x `!=` comparison is defined to be invert of whatever `__eq__` returns.

I thought that object ids are compared, in this case, assuming that we do not have singleton, all `!=` comparisons would have to return `True`. But apparently the same code on different environments was producing different results, so I guess, there is something else which is compared instead of object ids.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wouldn't use explicit `__ne__` in your class definition, then `__ne__` from inherited `object` will be used. It works like following code (but of course original is written in C):

```
def __ne__(self, other):
    eq_result = self == other
    if eq_result is NotImplemented:
        return NotImplemented
    else:
        return not eq_result
```

So because you're comparing user-defined classes, then `id` is being used.

Here is the source code [source code](https://svn.python.org/projects/python/branches/r22rc1-branch/Objects/typeobject.c). Look at `slot_tp_richcompare`.

Comment: Where did you take it from? Do you have a link to C implementation of this functionality ?

Comment: The python code here is highly misleading. Python 2.7 (as opposed to 3.x) does not use `__eq__` (as implied by this code) if `__ne__` is not defined. Instead it used the `id` (as you say), even id `__eq__` is defined independent of the id.

Answer (score 0):

turkus' answer is correct: if no `__ne__()` method is specified, the inverse of the result of the `__eq__()` method is returned. The relevant part of the CPython source is `slot_tp_richcompare()`:

```
static PyObject *
slot_tp_richcompare(PyObject *self, PyObject *other, int op)
{
    PyObject *res;

    if (Py_TYPE(self)->tp_richcompare == slot_tp_richcompare) {
        res = half_richcompare(self, other, op);
        if (res != Py_NotImplemented)
            return res;
        Py_DECREF(res);
    }
    if (Py_TYPE(other)->tp_richcompare == slot_tp_richcompare) {
        res = half_richcompare(other, self, _Py_SwappedOp[op]);
        if (res != Py_NotImplemented) {
            return res;
        }
        Py_DECREF(res);
    }
    Py_INCREF(Py_NotImplemented);
    return Py_NotImplemented;
}
```

If `__ne__()` is not defined, the opposite method (defined in `_Py_SwappedOp[op]` as `Py_EQ`, i.e. `__eq__()`, for `Py_NE`) is called. A comment in `classobject.c` shows what happens should `__eq__()` not be defined:

> /* If there is no `__eq__` and no `__cmp__` method, we hash on the
>         address.  If an `__eq__` or `__cmp__` method exists, there must
>         be a `__hash__`. */

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, the opposite of `Py_EQ` defined in `_Py_SwappedOp[op]` is `Py_EQ`. Swapping only means swapping left and right side, so `a!=b` is swapped to `b!=a`. (Note that `a<b` gets swapped to `b>a`. So even if `__eq__` is defined, python 2.7 (as opposed to 3.x) des not use it for `__ne__`. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4352244/python-should-i-implement-ne-operator-based-on-eq