# Should __eq__ compare objects of two different types?

Tags: python, python-2.7

In the problem I'm working, there are data identifiers that have the form `scope:name`, being both `scope` and `name` strings. `name` has different parts separated by dots, like `part1.part2.part3.part4.part5`. On many occasions, but not always, `scope` is just equal to `part1` of `name`. The code I'm writing has to work with different systems that provide or require the identifiers in different patterns. Sometimes they  just require the full string representation like `scope:name`, on some other occasions calls have two different parameters `scope` and `name`. When receiving information from other systems, sometimes the full string `scope:name`is returned, sometimes `scope` is omitted and should be inferred from `name` and sometimes a dict that contains `scope` and `name` is returned.

To ease the use of these identifiers, I have created a class to internally manage them, so that I don't have to write the same conversions, splits and formats over and over again. The class is quite simple. It only has two attributes (`scope` and `name`, a method to parse strings into objects of the class, and some magic methods to represent the objects Particularly, `__str__(self)` returns the object in the form `scope:name`, which is the fully qualified name (fqn) of the identifier:

```py
class DID(object):
    """Represent a data identifier."""

    def __init__(self, scope, name):
        self.scope = scope
        self.name = name

    @classmethod
    def parse(cls, s, auto_scope=False):
        """Create a DID object given its string representation.

        Parameters
        ----------
        s : str
            The string, i.e. 'scope:name', or 'name' if auto_scope is True.

        auto_scope : bool, optional
            If True, and when no scope is provided, the scope will be set to
            the projectname. Default False.

        Returns
        -------
        DID
            The DID object that represents the given fully qualified name.

        """
        if isinstance(s, basestring):
            arr = s.split(':', 2)
        else:
            raise TypeError('string expected.')

        if len(arr) == 1:
            if auto_scope:
                return cls(s.split('.', 1)[0], s)
            else:
                raise ValueError(
                    "Expecting 'scope:name' when auto_scope is False"
                )
        elif len(arr) == 2:
            return cls(*arr)
        else:
            raise ValueError("Too many ':'")

    def __repr__(self):
        return "DID(scope='{0.scope}', name='{0.name}')".format(self)

    def __str__(self):
        return u'{0.scope}:{0.name}'.format(self)
```

As I said, the code has to perform comparisons with strings and use the string representation of some methods. I am tempted to write the `__eq__`  magic method and its counterpart `__ne__`. The following is an implementation of just `__eq__`:

```py
    # APPROACH 1:
    def __eq__(self, other):
        if isinstance(other, self.__class__):
            return self.scope == other.scope and self.name == other.name
        elif isinstance(other, basestring):
            return str(self) == other
        else:
            return False
```

As you see, it defines the equality comparison between both DIDs and strings in a way that is possible to compare one with the other. **My issue with this is whether it is a good practice**:

On the one hand, when `other` is a string, the method casts `self` to be a string and I keep thinking on *explicit better than implicit*. You could end up thinking that you are working with two strings, which is not the case of self.

On the other hand, from the point of view of meaning, a `DID` represents the fqn `scope:name` and it makes sense to compare for equality with strings as it does when an int and a float are compared, or any two objects derived from `basetring` are compared.

I also have thought on not including the basestring case in the implementation, but to me this is even worse and prone to mistakes:

```py
    # APPROACH 2:
    def __eq__(self, other):
        if isinstance(other, self.__class__):
            return self.scope == other.scope and self.name == other.name
        else:
            return False
```

In approach 2, a comparison for equality between a DID object and a string, both representing the same identifier, returns `False`. To me, this is even more prone to mistakes.

Which are the best practices in this situation? Should the comparison between a DID and a string be implemented as it is in approach 1, even though objects from different types might be considered equal? Should I use approach 2 even though `s != DID.parse(s)`? Should I not implement the `__eq__` and `__ne__` so that there are never misunderstoods?

Comment: Have you ever tried `1 == 1.0`? Note however that `__eq__` does not exist in isolation... that's why `hash(1) == hash(1.0)`, you don't want to break Liskov principle with a custom implementation of `__eq__` that braks hashing of subclasses or stuff like that...

Comment: For the record, if you're on Python 2, and you implement `__eq__`, make sure to [implement `__ne__` in terms of `__eq__`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35781654/364696); Python 3 will do this for you, Python 2 will not.

Comment: Duck typing would suggest you simply try the attribute comparison, and if an `AttributeError` gets raised, then fall back to string comparison. Don't worry about the exact type of `other`.

Comment: @GiacomoAlzetta, you formally pointed out my concerns with the approach I'm proposing. `__eq__` does not exist in isolation. Thanks.

Comment: @ShadowRanger. I took that into account. It's something important to take into account when stuck in Python 2.

Comment: @chepner, I also implemented a version with the duck typing behaviour that you mention, but somehow it was even more rare to allow comparison of two objects bases on the fact that they have an scope attribute and a name attribute, which is the idea of duck typing. [This post](https://devinpractice.com/2016/11/29/python-objects-comparison/) explains why I discarded your approach.

Answer (score 3):

A few classes in Python (but I can't think of anything in the standard library off the top of my head) define an equality operator that handles multiple types on the RHS.  One common library that does support this is NumPy, with:

```
import numpy as np

np.array(1) == 1
```

evaluating to `True`.  In general I think I'd discourage this sort of thing, as there are lots of corner cases where this behaviour can get tricky.  E.g. see the write up in Python 3 [`__hash__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__hash__) method (similar things exist in Python 2, but it's end-of-life).  In cases where I have written similar code, I've tended to end up with something closer to:

```
def __eq__(self, other):
    if isinstance(other, str):
        try:
            other = self.parse(str)
        except ValueError:
            return NotImplemented

    if isinstance(other, DID):
        return self.scope == other.scope and self.name == other.name

    return NotImplemented
```

Further to this, I'd suggest making objects like this immutable and you have a few ways of doing this.  Python 3 has nice [dataclasses](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html), but given that you seem to be stuck under Python 2, you might use `namedtuple`s, something like:

```
from collections import namedtuple

class DID(namedtuple('DID', ('scope', 'name'))):
    __slots__ = ()

    @classmethod
    def parse(cls, s, auto_scope=False):
       return cls('foo', 'bar')

    def __eq__(self, other):
        if isinstance(other, str):
            try:
                other = self.parse(str)
            except ValueError:
                return NotImplemented

        return super(DID, self).__eq__(other)
```

which gives you immutability and a repr method for free, but you might want to keep your own str method.  The `__slots__` attribute means that accidentally assigning to `obj.scopes` will fail, but you might want to allow this behaviour.

Comment: Note: I'd suggest returning `NotImplemented` rather than `False` when you don't know how to compare the types. That allows the right hand side's `__eq__` to be checked (in case it knows how to perform the comparison).

Comment: @ShadowRanger yup, that's probably better!  not sure if it'll matter here though, we know the RHS is a `str` and hence it'll only ever return `False`  won't it?  maybe if somebody else subclasses it?

Comment: We know *nothing* about the RHS. It's the case where it's *not* a `str` or a `DID` that returning `NotImplemented` handles (it's needed more in your first `__eq__` example than your second). You're planning for code reuse; at some point in the future, someone else may write some other class that should be comparable to `DID`. If you don't write a proper `__eq__`, then whether the equality comparison is performed correctly will depend on order; `did == didcomparable` always return `False`, while `didcomparable == did` would return `True` when appropriate. `NotImplemented` fixes the former.

Comment: oops, sorry I forgot about that line!  had moved on to other things, and was only thinking about the class I wrote at the bottom.  what you said is of course valid

Comment: @SamMason as you guess, I'm stuck in Python2. I wasn't aware of namedtuples. In the solution you propose, `__eq__` has also been extended to compare `DID`s and tuples, named or not, i.e. `DID('foo', 'bar') == ('foo', 'bar')`. At this point, I have no strong opinion on this. As [doc](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple) states, subclassing when adding new fields deserves some attention: _Subclassing is not useful for adding new, stored fields. Instead, simply create a new named tuple type from the `_fields` attr_ i.e., there is no inheritance of methods.

Comment: @TrilceAC it also allows tuples because it just passes everything off to `super.__eq__`, you could explicitly check that `other` is an instance of `DID` first, otherwise return `NotImplemented`.  AFAIK, the "subclassing" comment in the docs is mostly because methods like the initialiser, str and eq won't see these added fields unless you do things officially.  it inherits methods just fine, you end up with a standard class, or I'm misunderstanding something again :)

Comment: @SamMason, look at how `Point3D` _inherits_ from `Point` at the [doc](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple): `Point3D = namedtuple('Point3D', Point._fields + ('z',))`. Inheritance would mean that there is an `hypot`method for `Point3D`, but trying to call hypot() on a Point3D raises an `AttributeError` exception.

Comment: `Point3D` doesn't "inherit" from `Point` it creates a new, independant, class that happens to use the same fields as `Point` with an additional field `z`!  this isn't what most people would mean when they talk about inheritance anyway.

Comment: @SamMason Right, but it is what the doc recommends when one wants to add a new stored field. This is why I pasted this sentence that should be taken into consideration: _Subclassing is not useful for adding new, stored fields. Instead, simply create a new named tuple type from the `_fields` attr_. You cannot inherit from `Point` because _is not useful for adding new, stored fields_. You should _create a new named tuple type from the `_fields`attr_ but it doesn't inherit. It seems that if you want to add a new field to the tuple, your only option is to reimplement almost all the class.

Answer (score 0):

This is something that was used in the other answer but only really explained in the comments. The best way to handle this is to explicitly handle cases your class is ready to handle and then to allow other classes to define how to handle your class if they want.

```py
class MyClass:

    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x

    def __eq__(self, other):
        if isinstance(other, MyClass):
            return self.x == other.x
        else:
            return NotImplemented


class YourClass:

    def __init__(self, y):
        self.y = y

    def __eq__(self, other):
        if isinstance(other, YourClass):
            return self.y == other.y
        elif isinstance(other, MyClass):
            return self.y == other.x
        else:
            return NotImplemented
```

By returning `NotImplemented`, you can allow other classes to figure out how they should compare to your class if they need to. If both classes return `NotImplemented` i.e. they don't know how to handle each other, then `==` will return `False`.