# How can I remove duplicated items from an objectlistview (wxpython)?

Tags: wxpython, items, objectlistview

I am newy in wxpython (and python too :)) and I am trying to do a custom program for me and to learn, but there is something I cannt do. I have looking for examples of Objectlistview but there aren't so much. I copy/paste/edit code from [here](http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2012/06/20/wxpython-introduction-to-drag-and-drop/) (last example) and I want to do something like this to avoid duplicated items:

```
self.olv = ObjectListView(self, style=wx.LC_REPORT|wx.SUNKEN_BORDER)
...
self.olv.SetDropTarget(MyFileDropTarget(self))
self.setFiles()
self.RemoveDuplicated(self.olv)

def RemoveDuplicated(self, X):
    for all in X:
        Counter = 0
        for B in X:
            if X.path(A) == X.path(B):
                Counter += 1
            if (X.path(A) == X.path(B) and Counter >=2):
                 Counter += 1
                 RemoveObject(B)
```

Any idea or tutorial to do it? Thank you in advance.

Done now :D, ty Mike again.

```
     def __init__(self, window):
    """Constructor"""
    wx.FileDropTarget.__init__(self)
    self.window = window
    self.all_filenames = []


#----------------------------------------------------------------------
def OnDropFiles(self, x, y, filenames):
    """
    When files are dropped, update the display
    """
    self.entriesList = list()   # Actual dropped file entries; duplicates are avoided.
    self.haveEntries = False    # Tracks actual dropped file entries, but not help entries.

    self.RemoveDuplicated(self.all_filenames, filenames)
    self.all_filenames += filenames
    self.window.updateDisplay(filenames)

    print len(all_filenames) , len(filenames)

def RemoveDuplicated(self, X, Y):
    for A in X:
        for B in Y:
            if A == B:
                Y.remove(B)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since what you add to an ObjectListView is basically a list of objects or dicts, you could just run your de-dupe process on that list before setting the widget to those values. You could use Python's set function plus the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3942303/how-does-a-python-set-check-if-two-objects-are-equal-what-methods-does-an-o) to de-dupe the objects.

There are a couple of places to look for ObjectListView information:

- http://wiki.wxpython.org/ObjectListView
- http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2011/11/10/wxpython-and-sqlalchemy-an-intro-to-mvc-and-crud/
- http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2009/12/23/wxpython-using-objectlistview-instead-of-a-listctrl/