# How to override operator "in" in set of objects of my own class(Point)?

Tags: class, python-3.x, hash, operator-overloading, overriding

I have my own class

```
    class Point():
        def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
```

I need to make working in, for example this should return true:

```
    s = set()
    s.add(Point(5,5))
    b = Point(5,5)
    print(b in s)
```

Comment: `__eq__` and `__hash__` - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3942303/how-does-a-python-set-check-if-two-objects-are-equal-what-methods-does-an-o (This is not "overriding" the operator, but simply making `set.__contains__` "work" with your objects.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't override `in` specifically, you make your type hashable in the right way and many capabilities (including but not limited to `set.__contains__`) start to work. When you just want to consider equality over a set of attributes, the easiest way is to delegate to tuples:

```
class Point:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.x == other.x and self.y == other.y

    def __hash__(self):
        return hash((self.x, self.y))
```

Note however that you can't sensibly mutate a Point once it's been inserted. Because mutation changes the hash value (according to this new definition of `__hash__`), you "lose access" to prior values, and basically leak them:

```
p = Point(1, 2)
s = {p}
p.x = 3
assert p not in s
# ... even though ...
assert list(s)[0] == p
```

Even more insidious: *Sometimes* it *might* work by chance, due to hash collisions.